# Running ant task in maven manually after another plugin executes

Tags: maven, kotlin, maven-antrun-plugin

I want to be able to run [detekt](https://detekt.dev/docs/gettingstarted/mavenanttask) with `--auto-correct` as a maven task not tied to a specific phase, e.g. during local development to format source files. I created an execution inside maven-antrun-plugin without phase:

```
<execution>
  <id>detekt-format</id>
    <goals>
      <goal>run</goal>
    </goals>
...
```

I can run it with `mvn -pl my-project antrun:run@detekt-format`.
The problem is that I have a multi-module project structure, and detekt configuration is placed in parent pom dir (root directory). I use `directory-maven-plugin` to get the highest directory (since ${basedir} is tied to module directories).
THE PROBLEM: when I manually run this task I don't have access to the root directory path generated by `directory-maven-plugin`, is it possible with maven to run this plugin before running `maven-antrun-plugin`?

directory-maven-plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.commonjava.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>directory-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>directories</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>highest-basedir</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <configuration>
                <property>RootDir</property>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Why not https://github.com/Ozsie/detekt-maven-plugin ?

Comment: @JFabianMeier that original project setup relies on io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt.detekt-cli used in ant task. I will see if what you propose can help here.